# How to fix valueerror invalid literal error in django?

Tags: python, django, url, view, model

I'm getting this error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'social'` when I try to open a page at /category/social/.

```
def all_partners(request,category):
    p = Content.objects.filter(category_id=category)
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/category.html', {'p':p},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))


class ContentCategory(models.Model):
    content_category = models.CharField('User-friendly name', max_length =  200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content_category

class Content(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ContentCategory)
    external = models.CharField('User-friendly name', max_length =  200, null=True, blank=True)
    host = models.CharField('Video host', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.CharField('slug', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug

url(r'^category/(?P<category>[-\w]+)/$', 'all_partners'),
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I think the error is in the `"p = Content..."` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your view, `category` has to be an integer, or a string which can be casted to an int like `int('5')`. You must be going to a url which does not restrict the category to be an integer:

```
foosite.com/category/social/
```

So if the last part of the url maps to the `category` parameter, then within the view, within the query, it tries to cast `social` to an integer, which raises an error.

To solve it you either have to restring the url pattern to only allow numbers or change how the query is done.

```
# urls.py
url(r'^category/(?P<category>\d+)/$', 'all_partners'),
```

or

```
def all_partners(request,category):
    p = Content.objects.filter(category__content_category=category)
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/category.html', {'p':p},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

which will then lookup the categories by the name, not by the id.